# Modify CSS of parent class

Tags: html, css, angular

I have `Component A` with the following html:

```
<main>
  <div class="wrapper animated fadeIn">
    <div class="card card-dynamic-height">
      <ac-daily-entry-table *ngIf="employee" [employeeEmail]="employee.email"></ac-daily-entry-table>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

It has `DailyEntryTableComponent` as its child. I would like to find a way to modify the css of `Component A` inside `DailyEntryTableComponent` like this for example:

```
somethingChanged(something) {
  //modify the css of the class wrapper from my parent here
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `Output` property and then when it changes update the CSS property using `[class.yourClassName]`. Let me show an example:

daily-entry-table.component.html:

```
@Output() change = new EventEmitter();
onClick() {
    this.change.emit({newValue: true } );
}
```

and then it can be used like this in `Component A`:

```
<main>
  <div class="wrapper animated fadeIn">
    <div class="card card-dynamic-height"
      [class.yourClass]="applyStyle">
      <ac-daily-entry-table *ngIf="employee" 
        (change)="onFooChanged($event)"
        [employeeEmail]="employee.email"></ac-daily-entry-table>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

componentA.component.ts:

```
applyStyle = false;

onFooChanged(event) {
    this.applyStyle = true;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in your child's `@Component` to disable encapsulation, this should allow you to override the parent's CSS.

Example:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './component-a.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-a.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```